# Firebase Realtime Database JS Error : Reference.set failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

I get this error in my cloud function

```
Error: Reference.set failed: First argument contains NaN in property 'server.saving-data.fireblog.history.newid.Id'
    at validateFirebaseData (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1497:15)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1534:13
    at each (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1517:9)
    at /workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1534:13
    at each (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:554:13)
    at validateFirebaseData (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1517:9)
    at validateFirebaseDataArg (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:1475:5)
    at Reference.set (/workspace/node_modules/@firebase/database/dist/index.node.cjs.js:13928:9)
    at /workspace/index.js:44:20
```

the js code that i have typed is as follows

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();
var db = admin.database();
var ref = db.ref("server/saving-data/fireblog");


exports.addHistory = functions.database.ref('issue/{id}').onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
  const val = snapshot.val();
  var lastid;

  return admin.database().ref('history').orderByChild("Id").limitToLast(1).on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
      snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
          lastid = data.val().Id;
      
      });
      const timeElapsed = Date.now();
      const today = new Date(timeElapsed);
      var datetime=today.toUTCString();

      var newid = lastid + 1;
          var usersRef = ref.child("history");
          usersRef.set({
              newid: {
                  Lamp: val.Id,
                  Reported: datetime,
                  Completed:"",
                  Status:"Pending",
                  AssignedTo:"",
                  Id:newid
              }
          });
  });


});
```

This is where i need to add record
So i get the last Id in the current case is 2 and increment by 1 making 3 and add a new record with key 3

[image]

Rules have been set

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Since you're reading from `history`, and listening to `child_added` the `snapshot` in your callback gets called with an individual child node already. This means there's no need for `snapshot.forEach()`.

I'd also recommend using `once` instead of `on` here, as you don't want to keep the listener active after reading the value once.

Finally, you also need to return the promise from `usersRef.set()` to ensure the Cloud Function doesn't get aborted before the write to the database is completed.

All combined, that looks like this:

```
  return admin.database().ref('history').orderByChild("Id").limitToLast(1).once("child_added")
  .then(snapshot => {
      lastid = snapshot.val().Id;

      const timeElapsed = Date.now();
      const today = new Date(timeElapsed);
      var datetime=today.toUTCString();

      var newid = lastid + 1;
      var usersRef = ref.child("history");
      return usersRef.set({
          newid: {
              Lamp: val.Id,
              Reported: datetime,
              Completed:"",
              Status:"Pending",
              AssignedTo:"",
              Id:newid
          }
      });
  });
```